# Setup continuous integration / delivery on-premise with source control pointing to VS team services?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

Our project development effort uses visual studio 2013 on our government client laptops, but we pull source code from Visual Studio Team Services (externally). What would be the best approach to setup continuous integration & delivery on our government servers (DEV, Staging and Prod)? None of the servers have internet access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a Continuous Integration server installed on one of your machines with access to Visual Studio Team Services, you can then setup tasks on the CI server to do the deployment on other machines that do not have access to VSTS. I use TeamCity as my CI server of choice, but other CI servers have similar capabilities.

To setup TeamCity with VSTS see http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2014/09/teamcity-and-visual-studio-online-source-control/

To setup TeamCity to deploy ASP.Net applications see https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2014/04/continuous-delivery-to-iis-or-windows-azure-web-sites/